# token_get_all() returns different values on same php version

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I'm using PhpCS to detect wrong syntax in my code.
This tool use the function token_get_all however I have some inconsistency between PHP version (or even the same PHP version online)

The simplified code is :

```
var_dump(
    token_get_all('<? ?>')    
);
```

If I use PHP 7.3 on both this website the results are differents :
https://onlinephp.io/c/c30ec ==> the result is an array of 3 entries
https://3v4l.org/5Ih6Z#v7.4.3 ==> the result is an array of 1 entry

I have the same problem between a php version on docker and my ubuntu.

Does someone have any idea what is the cause of this issue ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: My expectation would be that short php tags are not enabled on the latter server

Comment: onlinephp.io has short tags enabled, 3v4l does not. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php#refsect1-function.token-get-all-examples - example #2 sort of explains it by not having a valid open tag.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. The magic you're looking for lies in the PHP ini setting [`short_open_tag(php-ini)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

[`token_get_all(php)`](https://php.net/token_get_all) relies on this setting, which can not be changed while PHP is already running (as it affects how the code is being tokenized that is currently running, compare [`include(php)`](https://php.net/include), [`require(php)`](https://php.net/require) etc.).

*onlinephp.io* has it enabled ([ref](https://onlinephp.io/c/4e886)) and *3v4l.org* disabled ([ref](https://3v4l.org/3UZLb#v7.4.3)).

---

**Pratical Consequences**

You also write how you use it:

> I'm using PhpCS to detect wrong syntax in my code.

This appears to me you're interested in **portable** PHP code, *portable* means that the code robustly executes despite some PHP configuration differences like the version or ini settings.

This requires to only use `<?php ... ?>` (standard)  or `<?= ... ?>` (echo variant) *PHP tags*<sup>1</sup>.

In your case of `<? ... ?>` (short open variant, not recommended) replace the opening `<?` with `<?php` (or add `php` directly after it).

Compare with the note in the manual<sup>1</sup>:

> As short tags can be disabled it is recommended to only use the normal tags (`<?php ?>` and `<?= ?>`) to maximise compatibility.

**In PhpCS** enable the `Generic.PHP.DisallowShortOpenTag` sniff and execute `phpcs` with the *short_open_tag* setting enabled (otherwise PhpCS can't do the work<sup>2</sup>). IIRC the `phpcbf` command then also automatically fixes the places -- don't change by hand that you can let the machine with the fine PhpCs tooling do on your fingertips.

The sniff will safe-guard (`phpcs`) your ongoing development when you occasionally fall back into the habit to type in a short open tage here or there, the fixer (`phpcbf`) can quickly correct it.

---

Examples executing on the command line where you can control the setting per each invocation:

**short open tag disabled (`short_open_tag=0`)**

```
$ php7.4 -d short_open_tag=0 -r 'var_export(token_get_all("<? ?>")); echo "\n";'
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 313,
    1 => '<? ?>',
    2 => 1,
  ),
)
```

**short open tag enabled (`short_open_tag=1`)**

```
$ php7.4 -d short_open_tag=1 -r 'var_export(token_get_all("<? ?>")); echo "\n";'
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 382,
    1 => '<?',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 385,
    1 => ' ',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 384,
    1 => '?>',
    2 => 1,
  ),
)
```

---

1. [PHP tags in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)
2. [Generic.PHP.DisallowShortOpenTag doesn't catch `<?` (squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer #1571)](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/1571)
3. [PHP RFC: Deprecate PHP Short open tags (by George Peter Banyard; March 2019)](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags)

Answer (score 0):

Because <? is deprecated tag since php 5.0, most PHP servers don't support them. Use <?php tag.

Comment: Technically incorrect - short open tags are deprecated, but not removed, you need to enable them as per [the php docs](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags)

Comment: @CanO'Spam: Also technically incorrect ;) - The docs have the ini setting here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag ^^ nevertheless I also stand corrected, good overview is here in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php